# login session facebook / upload photo

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, photo, facebook-wall

I have a question, I try to integrate facebook inside an application, for do it I follow [a tutorial](http://www.devapp.it/wordpress/t030-aggiungiamo-facebook-alle-nostre-applicazioni.html)

I do the login in this way

```
_facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId];
[_facebook authorize:_permissions delegate:self];
```

my question is, there is a way for maintain the login session? now every time I want to post on fb wall I have to login and then post.
Last question is, can I post a local image inside web image on wall post?

Answer (score 0):

Since each time you are creating _facebook object. After that you are calling the following method.  `[_facebook authorize:_permissions delegate:self];`

So for solving your problem maintain a session after successful login call code like this,

```
if(session)
 // write code here for post to wall
else
 // write your code for authentication
```

For better understanding you can follow this tutorial [easy Integration of Facebook in ios app](http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app)